# Using flex makes autocomplete list overlay on other element

Tags: css, react-native, autocomplete, flexbox

I am making autocomplete textbox by using flatlist.
I want to show a list on top of every element that I have.
Now when autocomplete show. it pushes another textbox away.

2 of Autocomplete Textboxes:

[image]

When textbox is showing a list and they push another textbox away:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
    <TextInput placeholder="search" onChangeText={(text) => this.populateList(text)} />
    <View>
      <FlatList
        style={{ position: 'absolute' }}
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
    <TextInput placeholder="search" />
```

Here is the component I used to test with:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  populateList = (text) => {
    var characters = text.split("");
    var data = [];
    characters.forEach(element => {
      data.push({ key: element });
    });
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput placeholder="search" onChangeText={(text) => this.populateList(text)} />
        <View>
          <FlatList
            style={{ position: 'absolute' }}
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
          />
        </View>
        <TextInput placeholder="search" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style "position: fixed" in your element style
Like below example:

```
<span style="position: fixed;" id="search_result"></span>
```